# Operator in separate python file fail to get registered variable from innit file

Tags: python

I have registered some variable to store some value/string through `def register()` in the `__innit__.py`. And I wrote an operator in a separate file trying to access that variable, but fail.

In the `__init__.py` I have register the following:

```
def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.myVariable= "sometext"

import bpy

from bpy.types import Operator

from bpy.props import (
    IntProperty,
    FloatProperty,
    StringProperty,
)
```

in the Operator file `my_operators.py` I tried

```
import bpy

from bpy.types import Operator

from bpy.props import (
        IntProperty,
        FloatProperty,
        StringProperty,
)

class MyOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "myops.addthings"
    bl_label = "Add Base Mesh"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    bl_description ="Add Base Mesh"    

    #this line tries to get the registered variable
    myVariable = bpy.context.scene.myVariable

def execute(self, context):
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to make a property to the scene object the wrong way in the `__init__.py` file line 2 `bpy.types.Scene.myVariable= "sometext` ... that is why this is failing to work. Also please put all `import` statements at the very top.

The correct way to do this in the `__init__.py` put

```
import bpy 

# This creates a new variable to the scene object that is a string 
# then assigns it the default value "sometext" 
bpy.types.Scene.myVariable = bpy.props.StringProperty(name = "myVariable", default = "sometext")

# Later on you can access the variable like this:
print(bpy.context.scene.myVariable) 

# Of course you can also modify it just like any other 
# variable
bpy.context.scene.myVariable = "Some other text" 
print(bpy.context.scene.myVariable)
```

Lemme know if you need to know anything else tried to explain it the best I could!